# trace of VoIP packet delay

Tags: statistics, network-protocols, voip

I am interested about packet delays due to network jitter in voip calls. The distribution of the delay should be something similar to a Gaussian distribution with heavy tail to the right of the peak, and truncated to the left. Does anyone know where I can find a trace to download of packets sent during a voip call?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply install 2 free VoIP clients and make a Wireshark trace yourself ?

For H.323 you could use [Spranto](http://www.spranto.com/) or [X-Lite](http://www.counterpath.com/x-lite.html) for SIP.